# Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoUploadException Unable to locate file to upload

Tags: php, laravel, vimeo

I'm using vimeo videos with PHP Laravel. When I try to upload video it gives me

> Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoUploadException Unable to locate file to upload.

This is my HTML:

```
   <div class="col-md-6">

                                <label>video:</label>
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="Video" id="Video"
                                        class="custom-file-input" />
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-md-none mb-2"></div>

                            </div>
```

and this is the controller

```
 $Video = $request->file('Video');
    $uri = Vimeo::upload($Video, array(
        "name" => $Video,
        "description" => "The description goes here."
    ));
```